# Vlookup with optional criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to lookup data, using optional criteria.

For example the input data may be :

```
Col1  Col2
Pig   Mouse
```

and the lookup table :

```
Col 1   Col2    Col3
Pig             1
Pig     Mouse   2
```

So this example would return 2. If just Pig was in the input data, it would return 1

Comment: What would you expect to happen if Pig was not in Col1?

Comment: Suppose you concatenate columns 1 and 2 in your lookup table, and then just perform a `VLOOKUP` on the concatenated input data?  Is that an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$7:$A$8=A2)*($B$7:$B$8=B2)*($C$7:$C$8))
```

This will return every value from columnC where ColumnA = A2 and ColumnB = B2, even if the values are blank.